# Send H264 encoded data via webrtc rtp layer

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtp, webrtc

I am trying to add H264 codec support to webrtc. I have encoded my video stream into H264 using x264 library. Now I need to send that encoded data via rtp layer. In webrtc code in rtp part I see some H264 related things but they are not included in the project and aren't used anyhow. They even are not complete. There are some pure virtual functions without implementation. 
Has anyone added H264 support? I wonder if you made use of the existing H264 staff or did everything on your own? Are there a lot of rtp layer changes, or with some minor modifications on VP8 related functions I can get what I want?

Comment: I have added H264 hardware encoder, replacing existing OpenH264 encoder, which can write its output to file. Now stuck on same RTP fragmentation header.